# R pass function in as variable

Tags: r, function, variables, arguments

I am working on a project to profile function outputs so need to pass a function in as an argument in R. To clarify, I have a varying number of models, and am not looking for assistance on setting up the models, just passing in the model function names into the scoring function.

This works for a direct call, but I want to make it more generic for building out the module. Here is a brief example:

```
#create a test function:
model1 = function(y,X){
fit = lm(y~X)
output = data.frame(resid = fit$residuals)
}

#score function:
score = function(y,X,model){
y= as.matrix(y) 
X = as.matrix(X)
fitModel = model(y,X)
yhat = y - fitModel$residual
output = data.frame(yhat=yhat)
}
```

I can call this code with valid y and X mats with

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(5),y=runif(5))
scoreModel1 = score(df$y,df$x,model1)
```

But what I am looking for is a method of listing all of the models, and looping through, and/or calling the score function in a generic way. For instance:

```
models = c("model1")
scoreModel1 = score(df$y,df$x,models[1])
```

The error that I get with the above code is

```
Error in score(y, X, model) : 
could not find function "model"
```

I have played around with as.function(), and listing and unlisting the args, but nothing works. For instance all the following args have rendered the same error as above

```
models = c(model1)
models = list(model1)
models = list("model1")
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The parts of your code that according to you should run gives an error for me. If you are only dealing with linear models you could pass a formula to your scoring functions.

Comment: Perhaps you should learn the difference btwn '[' and '[['. The second version should have worked with models[[1]]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`match.fun` is your friend. It is what `apply` `tapply` et al use for the same purpose. Note that if you need to pass arguments to the model fitting functions then you will either need to bundle all of these up into a function like so `function(x) sum(x==0, na.rm=TRUE)` or else supply them as a list and use `do.call` like so `do.call(myfunc, funcargs)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you!! `match.fun()` was exactly what I was looking for.  I can't believe it is that easy, but it is R, so I guess I can believe it.

Answer (score 27):

For anyone arriving here from google wondering how to pass a function as an argument, here's a great example:

```
randomise <- function(f) f(runif(1e3))
 
randomise(mean)
#> [1] 0.5029048 

randomise(sum)
#> [1] 504.245


randomise(function(x) (x)^2)
```

It's from Hadley's book found [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html)

Answer (score 13):

your list objects can simply be the functions directly. Maybe you can get some use out of this structure, or else take Roland's advice and pass formulas. Richiemorrisroe's answer is probably cleaner.

```
fun1 <- function(x,y){
    x+y
}

fun2 <- function(x,y){
    x^y
}

fun3 <- function(x,y){
    x*y
}

models <- list(fun1 = fun1, fun2 = fun2, fun3 = fun3)

models[["fun1"]](1,2)
 [1] 3
models[[1]](1,2)
 [1] 3

lapply(models, function(FUN, x, y){ FUN(x = 1, y = 2)})
$fun1
 [1] 3

$fun2
 [1] 1

$fun3
 [1] 2
```

Comment: You should give different names to the functions' names : `models <- list(funct1 = fun1, funct2 = fun2, funct3 = fun3)` to avoid confusion

Answer (score 4):

another response:

```
models = list(model1)
scoreModel1 = score(df$y,df$x,models[[1]])
```

Example to pass function in as variable:

```
f_add<- function(x,y){ x + y }
f_subtract<- function(x,y){ x - y }
f_multi<- function(x,y){ x * y }

operation<- function(FUN, x, y){ FUN(x , y)}

operation(f_add, 9,2)
#> [1] 11
operation(f_subtract, 17,5)
#> [1] 12
operation(f_multi,6,8)
#> [1] 48
```

good luck